# How do I get the DOM node within a YUI event handler?

Tags: javascript, dom, yui3

Given a generic handler bound to a series of links with YUI, how do I find out which link triggered the event?

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
    var list = Y.one('#studentList'), links;
    links = list.all('a');
    links.on('click', function (e) {
        alert(this.get('id')); // this just shows a comma delimited list of all ids
    });
});
```

I suppose I could bind each link individually instead of using the "on" idiom on the links list, but it seems odd to me that YUI would not provide access to the DOM node. Digging into the event object shows several private fields that look like the DOM node, but surely there must be a safe way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`e.currentTarget`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DOMEventFacade.html#property_currentTarget) appears to be what you're looking for:

```
links.on('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget.get('id'));
});
```

From [NodeList's `on`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/NodeList.html#method_on):

> By default, the `this` object will be the `NodeList` that the subscription came from, *not the `Node` that received the event*. Use `e.currentTarget` to refer to the `Node`.